Reference for formula listed in OEIS A080934
OEIS A080934 is the square array read by antidiagonals of number of Catalan paths of $2n$ steps with all values less than or equal to $k$. The $n$th row of the table is the sequence that counts the number of Catalan paths bounded by height $n$. One of the formulas listed for the generating function of the $n$th row is listed without reference, and I am hoping to locate a reference.
The formula for the generating function of the $n$th row is
$\frac{B(n)}{B(n+1)}$, where $B(j) = \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^j - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^j$

This was originally one of mine in 2003.  That generating function was added to the entry by Neil Sloane on Apr 09 2005 at the same time that he added the references from C. Krattenthaler ( Permutations with restricted patterns and Dyck paths, arXiv:math/0002200 [math.CO], 2000. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002200 ) and from T. Mansour and A. Vainshtein ( Restricted permutations, continued fractions and Chebyshev polynomials, arXiv:math/9912052 [math.CO], 1999-2000. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9912052 ), so I would look there first.
